# SQL SELECT Statement for selecting values of a particular field and display all the rows

Tags: c#, sql

How can I display contents of a complete row  by searching a particular column name using sql query?

I tried to write the query like this:

```
s = "select RegNo, FirstName, LastName,JobTittle,TotalExperienceYear,TotalExperienceMonth,AreaPrefered,MobileNo from EmployeeRegistration where RegNo like '%" + reg + "' or FirstName like '%" + reg + "' or LastName like '%" + reg + "' or JobTittle like '%" + reg + "' or TotalExperienceYear like '%" + reg + "' or TotalExperienceMonth like '%" + reg + "' or AreaPrefered like '%" + reg + "' or MobileNo like '%" + reg + "%'";
```

But it selects the fields when it seems same values among different fields too..

Comment: You're creating a query by all the columns. Just put one column to check after `WHERE` clause

Comment: There are hundreds of samples of what you're trying to do in net. Just look at SQL Query tutorials

Comment: And of course tutorial about sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "SELECT
RegNo, FirstName, LastName,JobTittle,TotalExperienceYear,TotalExperienceMonth,AreaPrefered,MobileNo 
FROM EmployeeRegistration
WHERE RegNo like '%" + reg + "'";
```

Try this query. You are checking all the columns and it cant return a thing because FirstName, LastName, RegNo, JobTitle all these things cannot be like '%reg'

Answer (score 0):

s = "select RegNo, FirstName, LastName,JobTittle,TotalExperienceYear,TotalExperienceMonth,AreaPrefered,MobileNo,FatherName from EmployeeRegistration where RegNo like '%" + txtRno.Text + "%' AND FirstName like '%" + txtFstName.Text + "%' AND LastName like '%" + txtSecondName.Text +  "%' AND JobTittle like '%" + txtJobTittle.Text + "%' AND TotalExperienceYear like '%" + txtExpYear.Text + "%' AND TotalExperienceMonth like '%" + txtExpMonth.Text + "%' AND AreaPrefered like '%" + txtScndName.Text + "%' AND MobileNo like '%" + txtMobno.Text + "%' AND FatherName like '%" + txtFthrName.Text +"%'";